# Linking index.html with main.js file

Tags: javascript, html, vite

Webpage is empty, main.js file is not being linked despite them being in the same folder. Npt is used & Vite is used for 3d effects, cameras, etc.

index.html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title> Abd </title>
  </head>
  <body>
hello
    <canvas id="bg"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css code:

```
canvas { 
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

}
```

main.js code:
import './style.css'

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
const scene = new THREE.Scene();


const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.querySelector('#bg'),
});



renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );


camera.position.setZ(30);

renderer.render( scene,camera );
const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 10,3,16,100)
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 
0xFF6347,wireframe:true});
const torus=new THREE.Mesh( geometry,material);

scene.add(torus)



function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

animate()
```

[Empty webpage- javascript not being linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs4eK.png)

Comment: Did you try `src="main.js"`?

Comment: Are you testing locally? Check your browser console for any CORS errors.

Comment: @SvenCazier How can I do that?

Comment: @AbdullahAhmed For most, if not all, browsers on Windows (and Linux) ctrl + shift + j, on Mac, whatever ctrl + shift translate to + j. Or you could right click on the page, click inspect and then click on the console tab. If you have a message in red, saying something about CORS: it's a security issue with modules.

Answer (score 0):

Are these files in the root folder of your site? Using a `/` in your URL tells HTML that your file is found there. If that's your issue, you should be able to fix this just by changing `/main.js` to `main.js`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything:/

Answer (score 0):

Try to put:
`<script src=".js-path"> </script>`
to your `<head>` section

if the script file is in another directory you can access this by putting `"./"` before the script path

Answer (score -1):

there are a couple of things you need to look at.
First of all, JavaScript modules allow a program to be divided into multiple sequences of statements and declarations. `<script type=module>` is used to load JavaScript modules inside web pages.

To link a Javascript file to your HTML file, you have to use the `<script>` tag with a `scr` attribute. Since the javascript file is in the same folder as  the HTML file, you can write the tag like this: `<script src="main.js">` .

Good luck my friend.

Comment: type="module" specify that js files will be parsed as modules and ES6 imports can be used in the application, without it import will not work. The error is in the src attribute, if the files are in the same folder "./main.js" should be used